# "Where" clause in Entity Framework not retrieving child entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, where-clause, navigation-properties

Here's the deal.

I have two tables related in my model. We'll name'em: `reports` and `subReports`.

It's is very important to mention that I don't know, at this point, the `reportId` of the report I need, so I need to find it using some parameters.
Ok, so, if I need to query one element of `reports` via EntityFramework, I do the following:

```
reports myReport = context.reports.Where(r=> r.startYear.Equals(2014) && r.endYear.Equals(2015) && r.reportCategoryId.Equals(1)).SingleOrDefault();
```

This line retrieves the only report that matches the info.

But here's the problem. If I want to access the collection of `subReports` that `myReport` should have, it turns out that such collection is empty. This is my problem, I don't know why. My tables are correctly related.

The weird this is, if I change my query like this:

```
reports myReport = context.reports.Where(r=> r.reportId.Equals(1)).SingleOrDefault();
```

The related entities are loaded and the collection has the subreports it should have. See the difference? I had to pass the `reportId`, but this is not what I need, because, as I already told you, I don't know the `reportId`.

Do you know what's happening?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Well, you don't `Include` sub reports, so you need to allow lazy loading to get them afterwards. Something is disabling lazy loading in your first query. I can't tell what it is without more details. But since lazy loading *is* possible, the only difference I can think of is that in the first case lazy loading is disabled in the context.

Comment: I tried the Include thing. Turns out it was that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried any of these techniques?

This is from [this MSDN page about eager loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    // Load all blogs and related posts 
    var blogs1 = context.Blogs 
                          .Include(b => b.Posts) 
                          .ToList(); 

    // Load one blogs and its related posts 
    var blog1 = context.Blogs 
                        .Where(b => b.Name == "ADO.NET Blog") 
                        .Include(b => b.Posts) 
                        .FirstOrDefault(); 

    // Load all blogs and related posts  
    // using a string to specify the relationship 
    var blogs2 = context.Blogs 
                          .Include("Posts") 
                          .ToList(); 

    // Load one blog and its related posts  
    // using a string to specify the relationship 
    var blog2 = context.Blogs 
                        .Where(b => b.Name == "ADO.NET Blog") 
                        .Include("Posts") 
                        .FirstOrDefault(); 
}
```

**Some remarks on lazy and eager loading**

Generelly I tend to work without lazy loading. I like to know when my entities are loaded and when not (eager loading).

Lazy loading can be turned off

- completely by setting the respective property on the `DbContext`:

  `this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`
- for a specific entity when the navigation property is not marked virtual. For more info, see the linked MSDN article

Comment: `Include(r=> r.subReports)` didn't do the trick, but `Include("subReports")` was a real success. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I think that depends on the EF version you are using, it probably works in EF5 or EF6